# Incorporating fontawesome into texlive to allow for compilation

Tags: fontawesome, texlive-2018

Ultimately I want to make use of the fontawesome package, however I am getting build crashes running the code below. I believe this is due to the fact that fontawesome is not installed, but am having issues with determining/fixing this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
  Hello
\end{document}
```

I am compiling through pdflatex via atom and the script package on linux mint.

TeX has been installed on my computer through texlive via command line. `tlmgr --help` does work to provide a lengthy list of help content, but then when I try to write `tlmgr install fontawesome` as implied this does not function.

Similarly if I use the latex package in atom (which appears to point to the same build for TeX, I get the error: *File 'fontawesome.sty' not found.*

As such, my question is: How do I successfully add fontawesome to texlive? I think this will resolve the problem I am having with referencing the package and then allow me to make use of the package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run: `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` via command line. This installs a lot more than just the fontawesome package, but picks it up as well.

Comment: Is installing 1.6 GB(!!) of fonts really the only solution to this problem?