# Installing fontawesome5 on TeX Live: Alternative to texlive-fonts-extra

Tags: texlive, ctan, fontawesome, fontawesome5, apt-install

In [a related question regarding fontawesome](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440568/93377) the suggestion to be able to use `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` with TeX Live is to run `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra`.

Yet, this wants to download 600MB and extract to 1.6GB on the drive!

We are running our LaTeX "builds" on a CI machine in the could and we do not want that machine to take up 1.6GB for a single (cool) font.

**Question**: Is there any way we can just install *fontawesome5*, not all *texlive-fonts-extra*, for TeX Live? Or do we really have to [manually download and install it from CTAN?](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5?lang=en)

Comment: If you would use vanilla texlive instead of the linux package, you could use `tlmgr install fontawesome5` to install an individual package.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for your answer, I will have to look into that. As the command currently give me `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!) ; (see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md) ; TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf ; tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!` I will have to look at the documentation.

Comment: Don't use `tlmgr` if you use a linux texlive. Either install texlive from tug.org or have a look for already existing workflows. E.g. here is a github action example which uses zauguin/install-texlive@v3  and then install some packages from a list: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yaml

Comment: We currently use `teatimeguest/setup-texlive-action@v2` on our Github workflow, so I think it would work to just add `fontawesome5` to our list of packages there. But I also build the PDFs locally, and to be honest, I also do not want to download 1.6GB of fonts to my local machine, so finding a way around `texlive-fonts-extra` would still be nice.

Comment: Use vanilla texlive  on your local machine, then you can install packages individually (as an additional benefit you'll get a much more up-to-date version than in linux)

Comment: do you need pdflatex support (which is more complicated to install manually as you need multiple fonts and metrics and map files) or just luatex/xetex in which case all you need t do is install these https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome5/opentype into your linux vm either by hand or probably there is an apt package separate from texlive just for the opentype font installed as a linux system font.